# Passar valores de um checkbox em um array populando os não checados com algum valor

Tags: php

Estou tentando passar valores `checkbox` em um `array`, porém os campos não checados não popula o `array`. Preciso preencher os campos não checados com o valor "N" por exemplo:

Exemplo em um *loop* de 5 resultados:

```
<?php
while(5x) : ?>

    <td><input  name="ocultarsub[]" type="checkbox" value="S" <?php  if($ocultar_sub =='S'){echo "checked"; }  ?> ></td>

<?php 
endwhile; 
?>
```

Obtenho como saída:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "S" [1]=> string(1) "S" }
```

Preciso popular os não checados com a letra N por exemplo:

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "S" [1]=> string(1) "S" [2]=> string(1) "N" [3]=> string(1) "N" [4]=> string(1) "N"}
```

Comment: Cara, um jeito feio de se fazer, mas que resolveria, seria colocar um input hidden pra cada checkbox e fazer uma função em javascript pra mudar o valor do hidden quando o respectivo checkbox fosse alterado, dai o form enviaria os hiddens

Comment: mais facil q isso basta passar um array completo so com os valores e os ids q vc selecionou vc altera para s e o resto permanece igual

Comment: Mais os valores não checados não entra no array, fica sem key dai perdendo a referência. A solução pode embaixo do meu nariz, mais hoje a sexta está afetando.

Comment: Consegui resolver de outra forma, troquei o checkbox por dropdown, assim recebo o valor negado. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda. Precisa editar o título para fechada ou algo assim?